# Show in product page more data in product combination list - Prestashop 1.7

Tags: attributes, prestashop, combinations, product, smarty

I have a Prestashop 1.7.5 and I need to show in the product page some extra data in each combination, but without having to click to see it.

I would need to see the following data:

- Combination reference
- Combination stock
- combination stock location

I use the Warehouse template, I would have to add it in the file **\themes\warehouse\templates\catalog_partials\product-variants.tpl**, in the following foreach:

```
{foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
  <li class="input-container float-left">
    <input class="input-radio" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}"
            name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]"
            value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
    <span class="radio-label">{$group_attribute.name}</span>
  </li>
{/foreach}
```

Does anyone know how I could do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more complicated if a product has multiple attributes, because it is not the combinations that appear on the product page, but the properties from which the combination can be compiled.

For example: There is no choice on the product page for a white XL T-shirt, but you can select the XL size and then the color separately.

What you need is a combination matrix:
https://mypresta.eu/modules/front-office-features/product-page-combinations-table.html

Comment: Thanks for the possible solution, it seems that it can work, modifying the module later and adding the combination stock.